# WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 Xcode 6 with ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

when I am trying to use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
  NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
  [myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest]; 
}
```

in Xcode 6 and IOS 8 it's works fine! but when i try to do it on IOS 7 it's returning

> WebKitErrorDomain Code=101

**UPDATE:**
I try to compile it with Xcode 5 and it's works completely fine! I think it's Xcode 6 Bug!

Answer (score 0):

Google forces you to use https://www.google.com

101 Switching Protocols
This means the requester has asked the server to switch protocols and the server is acknowledging that it will do so.